# openGL bind multiple textures to quads

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I have to 6 quads that make up a cube and I want to bind different textures to each quad. How exactly could I do that? This what I have so far:

```
glPushMatrix(); {
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            //FrontFace
            if(id != Blocks.Air){
                setTexCords = true;
                glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                id.getFrontTexture().bind();
            }else{
                setTexCords = false;
                if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

                }else{
                    glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
                }
            }
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            {
            glEnd();


            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
            //BackFace
            if(id != Blocks.Air){
                setTexCords = true;
                id.getBackTexture().bind();
            }else{
                setTexCords = false;
                if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

                }else{
                    glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
                }
            }
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            }
            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
            //BottomFace
            if(id != Blocks.Air){
                setTexCords = true;
                id.getBottomTexture().bind();
            }else{
                setTexCords = false;
                if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

                }else{
                    glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
                }
            }
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);

            }
            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
            //TopFace
            if(id != Blocks.Air){
                glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                setTexCords = true;
                id.getTopTexture().bind();
            }else{
                setTexCords = false;
                if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

                }else{
                    glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
                }
            }
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);

            }
            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
            //LeftFace
            if(id != Blocks.Air){
                setTexCords = true;
                id.getLeftTexture().bind();
            }else{
                setTexCords = false;
                if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

                }else{
                    glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
                }
            }
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);

            }
            glEnd();

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {

            //Right Face
            if(id != Blocks.Air){
                setTexCords = true;
                id.getRightTexture().bind();
            }else{
                setTexCords = false;
                if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

                }else{
                    glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
                }
            }
            if(textureType == "IMAGE"){

            }else{
                glColor3d(toFloatColor(tid.getRed()), toFloatColor(tid.getGreen()), toFloatColor(tid.getBlue()));
            }
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex3f(Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
            if(setTexCords) glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex3f(-Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE,Blocks.BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
    glEnd();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
```

Every time I run the app the top just comes up black and the rest are the same texture.
Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change texture binding within a glBegin/glEnd block. This is a state that must be changed while no primitive is being drawn. That being said: Don't use glBegin/glEnd, also called the immediate mode. It's been deprecated and removed from modern OpenGL. Use Vertex Arrays instead, ideally with a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO).

Also instead of switching textures you should use a texture array.

Comment: You can't use array textures in fixed-function GL.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Well, I was suggesting to use texture arrays in addition to abandoning fixed function.

Comment: I updated my code to use Vertex arrays now, but thanks anyways